# New values are not binding with form backing object when posting in seam

Tags: jsf, xhtml, seam

I have multiple forms that are populated by ThingPageBean. Each of these forms are submitted with a `<h:commandButton>` where the action is set to call `#{thingPageBean.doAmazingThing(oneStuff)}`. All fields are static except for contactEmail and contactPhone where I want to use `<h:inputText>` instead of `<h:outputText>` so that the user can set a new value if they wish.

The problem is that the new values are not bound to object that is received in `doAmazingThing(OneStuff oneStuff)` in the `ThingPageBean`. The old ones remain.

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed some crucial part?

My Bean:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
@AutoCreate
@Name("thingPageBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
@Restrict("#{s:hasRole('admin')}")
public class ThingPageBean implements Serializable {

    @In
    StuffService stuffService;

    @In
    private StatusMessages statusMessages;


    public String doAmazingThing(OneStuff oneStuff) {
        return this.stuffService.doAmazingStuffToThing(oneStuff);    
    }

    @Factory(value = "notHandledStuff")
    public List<Stuff> notHandledStuff() {
        return this.stuffService.searchNotHandledStuff();
    }
}
```

My xhtml file:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
                template="/layout/SiteTemplate.xhtml">


    <ui:param name="robots" value="noindex"/>

    <!-- hide blocks -->
    <ui:param name="preContentHide" value="true"/>

    <ui:define name="mainContent">

            <c:set var="stuff" value="#{notHandledStuff}"/>
            <s:div styleClass="section"
                   rendered="#{stuff == null or stuff.size==0}">
                <h:outputText value="#{messages['stuff.no']}"/>
            </s:div>
            <s:div styleClass="section"
                   rendered="#{stuff != null and stuff.size>0}">
                <br/>
                <ui:repeat var="oneStuff" value="#{stuff}">
                    <h:form id="stuffForm">
                        <hr style="margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:4px;"/>
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Company name:</b></td>
                                <td width="780px"><h:outputText value="#{oneStuff.companyName}"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>street:</b></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{oneStuff.street}"/></td>
                                <td/>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>zip:</b></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{oneStuff.zip}"/></td>
                                <td/>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>city:</b></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{oneStuff.city}"/></td>
                                <td/>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top:10px"><b>contactPerson:</b></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{oneStuff.contactPersonName}"/></td>
                                <td/>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>contactEmail:</b></td>
                                <td><h:inputText value="#{oneStuff.contactEmail}"/></td>
                                <td/>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>contactPhone:</b></td>
                                <td><h:inputText id="contactPhone" value="#{oneStuff.contactPhone}"/></td>
                                <td/>
                            </tr>

                                    <h:commandButton id="submit"  value="couple"
                                                     action="#{thingPageBean.doAmazingThing(oneStuff)}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                      </s:div>
                    </h:form>
                </ui:repeat>

                <hr style="margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:4px;"/>
            </s:div>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Thank you
Jakob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with multiple forms. Moved the `<h:form>` tag outside `<ui:repeat>` tag and voila everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change your `@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)`

> The event (request) context: spans a server request, from restore view to render response.

to a page scope: `@Scope(ScopeType.PAGE)`

> Begins during the invoke application phase prior to rendering a page, and lasts until the end of any invoke application phase of a faces request originating from that page. Non-faces requests do not propagate the page scope.

because you do need these data for a longer conversation not only an event (quotes from [Seam Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1BETA1/api/org/jboss/seam/ScopeType.html))